# Microsoft Access Like/Not Like

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, sage-erp

I seem to be having issues with MS Access in the following query based on a SAGE database

The following code does not work - it doesn't like the "NOT like" part

```
SELECT tran_number, Inv_ref, Details, date, Net_amount, amount_paid
FROM AUDIT_HEADER

WHERE type = 'BP' and 
deleted_flag= 0 and details NOT like "*WAGES*"
```

This code does work but is very slow and doesn't work when I link it to excel -

> parameters expected = 1 error??

```
SELECT tran_number, Inv_ref, Details, date, Net_amount, amount_paid
FROM AUDIT_HEADER

WHERE type = 'BP' AND deleted_flag= 0 and 
details NOT IN (SELECT details from audit_header where details like "*WAGES*");
```

Also, bizarrely, this code works, but obviously, I want to exclude transactions that include WAGES in the details

```
SELECT tran_number, Inv_ref, Details, date, Net_amount, amount_paid
FROM AUDIT_HEADER

WHERE type = 'BP' and 
deleted_flag= 0 and details like "*WAGES*"
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it returns ODBC Call Failed - Syntax - Invalid filter in WHERE clause (#0)

Comment: Try NOT ALIKE('%WAGES%')

Answer (score 1):

Since this works:

```
SELECT tran_number, Inv_ref, Details, date, Net_amount,
amount_paid FROM AUDIT_HEADER
WHERE type = 'BP' and 
deleted_flag= 0 and details like "*WAGES*"
```

While above does have a mix of single and double quotes (hint: in the future when trying to fix something with computers – being consistent is VERY important).

The only REAL issue that jumps out in above is that date is reserved word in Access. Details is also. Thus place [] brackets around the above reserved words

So you MUST MUST MUST verify that the follow as you claim works:

```
SELECT tran_number, Inv_ref, Details, date, Net_amount,
amount_paid FROM AUDIT_HEADER
WHERE type = "BP" and 
deleted_flag= 0 and details like "*WAGES*"
```

Now try above with the reserved words in brackets like this:

```
SELECT tran_number, Inv_ref, Details, [date], Net_amount,
amount_paid FROM AUDIT_HEADER
WHERE type = "BP" and 
deleted_flag= 0 and [details] like "*WAGES*"
```

So note the [] around date and details.

Again, test the second above example.
If the above works, and you DOUBLE, AND TRIPLE checked, then this should also work:

```
SELECT tran_number, Inv_ref, Details, [date], Net_amount,
amount_paid FROM AUDIT_HEADER
WHERE type = "BP" and 
deleted_flag= 0 and [details] NOT like "*WAGES*"
```

if above fails, then a good possibility that the SAGE system does not support “NOT” for the like command.

So try the [] on the WORKING query. If the [] works, then try adding the NOT to the working query.

Answer (score 0):

The user also gets an error:

```
ODBC Call Failed - Syntax - Invalid filter in WHERE clause (#0)
```

If you're using an ODBC call and calling a non-Access DB from Access you need to check your SQL is valid for whichever DB you are calling. So if you were using SQL server you would use:

```
SELECT tran_number, Inv_ref, Details, date, Net_amount, amount_paid
FROM AUDIT_HEADER WHERE type = 'BP' and deleted_flag= 0 and details NOT LIKE '%WAGES%'
```

As SQL uses single quotes and not double quotes. This quotes point might be worth checking as you have used single quotes around 'BP' but double around "*WAGE*". In addition, the wild card is a percentage symbol. You might want to check this against whichever DB you are using.

Comment: This doesn't work, it returns ODBC Call Failed - Syntax - Invalid filter in WHERE clause (#0)

Comment: Hi Owen, check this new answer.

Comment: Access ODBC is the same regardless of the server side or data source. You ONLY have to change the SQL if your  using a pass-though. So the above wild cards don't change if your using SQL server or SAGE or whatever as the back end. And Access works just fine if you use double quotes.

Comment: It was just a suggestion as he was using an ODBC connection (like a pass-through) and that could have been the source of his problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
and NOT (details like "*WAGES*")
```

As a side note wildcards at the start of strings is going to be slow.

Comment: This doesn't work, it returns ODBC Call Failed - Syntax - Invalid filter in WHERE clause (#0)